# How do I use MP4Box to edit the boxes?

Tags: http-live-streaming, fmp4

I am trying to use MP4Box to edit the #EXT-X-MAP:URI="fragment_init.mp4" file used in HLS fMP4. My current approach is to dump the mp4 file to an xml file, edit the xml and then package back into an mp4 file. Firstly, the source gstgenerated.mp4 file is converted to 2sec HLS fragments:

```
MP4Box -dash 2000 -frag 2000 -profile full -out master.m3u8 -segment-name fragment_ gstgenerated.mp4
```

Then the newly created fragment_init.mp4 file is dumped to the default fragment_init_dump.xml file:

```
MP4Box -dxml fragment_init.mp4
```

But if I try to re-create the mp4 file with the -package option an error is generated:

```
C:\Users\KFerguson\Videos\PAR> MP4Box -package fragment_init_dump.xml -new init.mp4

Missing 4CC code for meta name - please use ABCD:fileName
Failed to package file
```

Can anyone help with interpreting this and comment if I am on the right path to the box editing objective?